# Reliability over a serial connection

Tags: c#, serial-port, reliability, ppp

I have two computers communicating over a serial modem.
I would like to have a reliability protocol on that line.

I have been looking into PPP, SLIP and RATP. Not all of them are the best fit, and I do not want to write all that code, especially if there is a good code base for that online.

Is there a library or code project in C# that can be used for that purpose?
If not what protocol should you recommend to implement?

The connection speed is 9600, but the amount of data sent is not very big, and speed is not a big issue. Simplicity and ease of development is!

Comment: The normal way to do this in a serial protocol would be to calculate the CRC of the message and append that at the end of the message. The receiver can check the CRC and send a NAK when it doesn't match. The sender should respond to the NAK by resending the message. When it's received correctly it should send an ACK to confirm the message has arrived properly. Google has plenty samples of how to implement CRC in C#. But the easiest way would be to switch to Ethernet and use TCP/IP and you'll get error handling for free...

Comment: You need to define what you mean by *"reliabilty"*. First there is the question of message integrity: is the received message the same as when sent?.  Then there's the question of were all sent messages received?  Were messages received in the correct order?  Is authentication required (e.g. are you concerned about man-in-the-middle attacks)?  These problems are not all solved by every "reliable" protocol.

Answer (score -1):

I always just add a CRC to each message, but my higher level protocols are self-synchronizing and loss tolerant by virtue of unsolicited state reports -- if a command is lost and the state doesn't change, that becomes apparent on the next state report.  Depending on whether your requirement is to detect or correct errors, and whether you can tolerate extra delays for retransmissions, you might need to look into a forward error correcting code.

Concepts of interest include message sequence numbers, acknowledgement, go-back-N vs selective retransmit, and minimum distance between codes (Hamming distance).

I definitely suggest you look at the design of TCP.  The basics are really pretty minimal for guaranteed in-order delivery.

Comment: @sawdust: Ahh, sorry about that.  I thought the edits had been in the system for a while before you commented.  Anyway, I agree that some additional explanation was desirable.  Still I am sure the line " Depending on whether your requirement is to detect or correct errors, and whether you can tolerate extra delays for retransmissions, you might need to look into a forward error correcting code." was in the very first version.